# Many games/programs completely lose connection when loading websites on another computer

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection

We have multiple computers in our household connected to a Linksys wireless router which is in turn connected to a Zoom ADSL modem. When someone is playing an online multiplayer game (anything from Battlefield to SWTOR), and someone else uses another computer to access a web page, more often than not, the multiplayer game loses connection entirely. It's not even a temporary loss of connection that quickly fixes itself, rather, it almost always requires the player to exit and re-enter the game. It's accompanied with a "connection lost" error in the game.

This issue only seems to happen to newer games and it's a frequent problem in our house. I think that it might be a router issue, kind of "locking out" all other connections until that one webpage is done loading. Any specific router/modem settings I should check out?

Comment: We don't do product recomendations on Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound, its not really a shopping recommendation, to me it looks like asking if this is a sign of a failing router or if something can be done to fix it... Where is the shopping recommendation?

Comment: Not looking for a recommendation on a router. I'm looking for settings that I ought to check on my router. For example, my port forwarding rules, which for the record are **not** the issue.

Comment: @Ramhound: This is not a product recommendation whatsoever, please stop downvoting questions that you barely read because that just comes over as rude... Welcome to the [summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/)!